# How to thow InvalidNameException in Customer class

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have to modify setter method and constructor of the Customer class to throw an InvalidNameException if the length of first_name and last_name field of customer class id less than six and has numbers/special characters.
SAMPLE INPUT : Jack

O/P : javax.naming.InvalidNameException.Customer.setFirstName(Customer.java:67)

I tried this code but it is showing errors.

```
import java.util.*;
class Customer
{
   String name;
   public void setFirstName(String name)
   {
     this.name = name;
     char a[] = name.toCharArray();
     if(a.length <6){
        throw new InvalidNameException();
        }
     else{
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
         MAtcher m = p.matcher(name);
         boolean b = m.find();
         if(!b){
              throw new InvalidNameException();
               }
         }
     }
 }
public class Source
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = sc.nextLine();
      Customer cus = new Customer();
      cus.setFirstName(name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message. Also Java is case sensitive. `MAtcher` is a typo.

Comment: Please correct the typo and please go through throw and throws statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.naming.*;

class Customer{ 
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public Customer(){
}

public Customer(String firstname, String lastname) throws InvalidNameException{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
    Matcher matcherf = pattern.matcher(firstname);
    Matcher matcherl = pattern.matcher(lastname);
    if((firstname.length() < 6) || (lastname.length() < 6) || matcherf.find() || matcherl.find()){
        throw new InvalidNameException(" ");
    }else{
      this.firstname = firstname;
      this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}

public void setFirstName(String firstname) throws InvalidNameException{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
    Matcher matcherf = pattern.matcher(firstname);
    if((firstname.length() < 6) || matcherf.find()){
        throw new InvalidNameException(" ");
    }else{
      this.firstname = firstname;
    }
}
 public void setLastName(String lastname) throws InvalidNameException{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
    Matcher matcherl = pattern.matcher(lastname);
    if((lastname.length() < 6) || matcherl.find()){
        throw new InvalidNameException(" ");
    }else{
      this.lastname = lastname;   
    }
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return lastname;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return ("Name = "+firstname+" "+lastname);
}    
}

public class Source{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidNameException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String first = sc.next();
    String last = sc.next();
     Customer c = new Customer();
     c.setFirstName(first);
     c.setLastName(last);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly your code having a compilation issue.

Once you are throwing an exception from method or caller of method thatit should also throws the same exception.

[throws explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)

```
import javax.naming.InvalidNameException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidNameException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        Customer cus = new Customer();
        cus.setFirstName(name);
    }
}
class Customer
{
    String name;
    public void setFirstName(String name) throws InvalidNameException {
        this.name = name;
        char a[] = name.toCharArray();
        if(a.length <6){
            throw new InvalidNameException();
        }
        else{
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
            boolean b = m.find();
            if(!b){
                throw new InvalidNameException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For achieving this you need to create a custom exception class. also, java is case sensitive so write code in a proper manner. below is an example of a custom exception. The custom exception will help you to create your own exception which should be inherited from the root **Exception** class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Rextester
{  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidNameException {
         String name = "mukes";
            Customer cus = new Customer();
            cus.setFirstName(name);
    }
}
class Customer {
    String name;

    public void setFirstName(String name) throws InvalidNameException {
        this.name = name;
        char a[] = name.toCharArray();
        if (a.length < 6) {
            throw new InvalidNameException("Invalid Name");
        } else {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
            boolean b = m.find();
            if (!b) {
                throw new InvalidNameException("Invalid Name");
            }
        }
    }
}

class InvalidNameException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    InvalidNameException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

here is working [example](https://rextester.com/JMET5120). I just removed the scanner here for showing quick output.

Comment: Error htrown while compiling above code.  :    Source.java:12: error: unreported exception InvalidNameException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
           throw new InvalidNameException();   What to do for that.